# iOS AttributedText Removing /n Line Breaks

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to put in some line spaces between various quotes that get collected.  The code I use is:

```
if (!self.theArray) {

        self.theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }


    NSString *doIt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ %@:%@", self.textstring, self.bookstring, self.chapterstring, self.versestring];
    [self.theArray addObject:doIt];
    NSString *theEnd = [self.theArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

    NSString *loadHTML = [@"<head> <style type='text/css'>a > img {pointer-events: none;cursor: default;}</style></head><b><div align=\"left\"><font size=5>"  stringByAppendingString:theEnd];
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[loadHTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    textView.attributedText = attributedString;
    [self performSelector:@selector(startTheProcess) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
    NSLog(@"ARRAY:  %@", self.theArray);
    NSLog(@"String:  %@", theEnd);
```

In the log of both the array and the NSAttributedString it shows the line breaks, but when the UIWebView shows it, the line breaks are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
NSString *theEnd = [self.theArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

with this,

```
NSString *theEnd = [self.theArray componentsJoinedByString:@"<br>"];
```